# php extension installed vs enabled

Tags: php, installation, php-extension, isenabled

I was running through a situation when i am unable to find if **extension enabled** and **extension installed**. I googled it did not get a direct answer.

I have two questions-

**que1**-

> How to check if an extension is installed ?

**que2**-

> How to check if that extension is installed then is it enabled or not?

I have found bunch of php functions like `get_loaded_extensions`, `extension_loaded`, `function_exixts` which i found has been used, but what is the exact difference between using each one of them?

Any help would be appreciated :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To check whether an extension is installed you should use the `get_loaded_extensions()` to get a list of all extensions that are installed. In order to check whether a specific extension is installed you could use `extension_loaded`. 
To check whether functions exist or not (function that come with the extension for example) you should use `function_exixts`.

Another possibility to check whether an extension is installed is by looking at your `phpinfo()` and browse for the extension you are looking for.

At the command line you could run `php -m` and then to get you all the modules and then `php -i` to see more about the configuration of it.

When you know the extension is installed you could enable it by looking at the php.ini file and search for `extension=extensionname.so` (when using Unix). when using Windows look for `extension=extensionname.dll`. When you cannot find this you will need to add it to the list with others that do exist.

Hope this helps.